# Flash looping causing variable value issues

Tags: flash, variables, loops

Flash keeps looping which is causing certain variables to add values constantly. E.g.

```
if (userWord.text == word){
 score = score + 1;
 trace(score);
}
```

That will constantly add one to "score" when a certain word is typed into a text box.

How do I add one to "score" without stopping the application or playing it once?

Comment: To stop a timeline from looping, you use the stop() command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an eventListener to your text field and have it react to Event.CHANGE:

```
userWord.addEventListener (Event.CHANGE, onWordChange);

function onWordChange (ev:Event) : void {
    if (userWord.text == word) {
        score = score + 1;
        trace (score);
    }
}
```